# Show and Hide in a Foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a foreach loop going through my posts and each loop produces an html card with info inside from each post.

I want to show and hide items within the card on only that one card not every card that has been loaded. But I will need something to differentiate between the individual cards so the javascript doesn't hide all the info on all of the cards.

I wanted to know if anyone knows how I can achieve this with a javascript function to search only in elements within that element and not search the whole page.

My current show hide method

```
function show_hide_button_one() {
    var a = document.getElementById("grid-item-1");
    var b = document.getElementById("grid-item-2");
    a.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function show_hide_button_two() {
    var x = document.getElementById("grid-item-1");
    var y = document.getElementById("grid-item-2");
    y.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

But with that method it shows and hides everything with the relative class
and not just for the card in use.

Its for lot's of posts. So I need a smarter route than my own method xD

pls help.

Comment: You can use the keyword `this` to get instance of the element. Also use `class` selectors instead of `id`. Maybe I can help you out if you can share me a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of different options. You can use HTML data attributes to give each card unique identifiers beyond just ID or class name, or you can just make each card's ID's unique based on the post info. (Be careful not to give more than one card the same ID, as that will mess up your code!)

Here is a good artice on HTML data attributes:
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-why-use-html5-custom-data-attributes/

PS - Also, do this instead:

```
function show_hide_button(c1, c2) {
    var a = document.getElementById(c1);
    var b = document.getElementById(c2);
    a.style.display = a.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
    b.style.display = b.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. - If you show us the forEach loop and the code you are using to generate the cards, I can give you a more thorough response as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must be having same id for all card. Have separate id for each card/button (whatever you are trying to hide). You will achieve what you desire.

Try doing this

//HTML

```
<div id="card1>
...
<button id="card1id1"></button>
<button id="card1id2"></button>
</div>

<div id="card2>
...
<button id="card2id1"></button>
<button id="card2id2"></button>
</div>
```

// JS

```
function show_hide_button_one(id1,id2) {
    var a = document.getElementById(id1);
    var b = document.getElementById(id2);
    a.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function show_hide_button_two(id1,id2) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id1);
    var y = document.getElementById(id2);
    y.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

// calling

```
show_hide_button_one("card1id1", "card1id1")
show_hide_button_two("card1id1", "card1id1")
```

Comment: But there is hundreds of posts

Comment: how are you rendering the posts?

Comment: I need to get unique I'ds and get those unique I'd's through havascript

Comment: I am using php to get them

Comment: may be you can get from server ... or just the iterator count ?

Comment: ok I'm with you there. makes sense. But then how to I get each ID with the javascript?

Comment: you mean where you are calling the functions ? how are you giving this option of hiding the buttons ?

Comment: I use the onclick function and call the function name

Comment: when you are calling the function you know about which post to hide there ?

Comment: it would be lot easier if you could share the html part and how are you rendering the posts there.

Comment: So it's a box with tabs in it and when you click one oof the tabs it must hide the other tabs and show the appropriate tab.

Comment: On a page where posts are been loaded through a for each loop

Comment: in the foreach loop where you rendering the buttons, you must be rendering the one the button which is responsible to show/hide the buttons .. you can pass the same ids generated from foreach loop to the show/hide functions from there